# Vertx default configuration file

Tags: java, maven, configuration, vert.x

is there a way how to make vertx load specified default configuration without doing:

```
java -jar my-fat.jar -conf /path/to/my/conf.json
```

I mean to make vertx use config file which is present in that `my-fat.jar`.

For simplicity I would like to have one config by default - maybe could be overriden from outside or maybe not for now. I have lot of microservices that runs independently and separately and I would like to produce them as jars, that are self sufficient.

Can this be done programmatically or maybe with maven?  
Thanks for help.

Comment: `-conf` simply calls `.setConfig()` on `DeploymentOptions` that are passed to the Verticle. You can do that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking into microservices I'd recommend to look into http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/ as it covers configuration specifically for it. However you're describing that you'd like to override the default config with a preset json, you can quickly achieve this by doing a helper method in these lines of thought:

```
public JsonObject config() {
  JsonObject json = Vertx.currentContext().config();
  if (json == null) {
    return new JsonObject(
      vertx.fileSystem()
        .readFileBlocking("Your-Hard-Coded-Fallback.json"));
  }
  return json;
}
```

Please note that this is a hack and be aware that you need to have the right context and that the vertx objects needs to be available so it's safe to call this from the `start()` method. For a proper solution I'd still recommend you to look at the `vertx-config` module.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved for my microservice
I pass the path to config files (separated by comma) to be used as an env variable during the deploy and then I wrote a small utility to read the config file(.properties in my case )

```
String fileSources = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv(FILE_PATHS_SYSTEM_PROPERTY_NAME))
        .orElse("");
```

```
if (!fileSources.isEmpty()) {
      for (String fileSourceName : fileSources.split(",")) {
        ConfigStoreOptions fileProperty =
            new ConfigStoreOptions()
                .setType("file")
                .setFormat(getTypeFromFileExtension(fileSourceName))
                .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", fileSourceName));
        options.addStore(fileProperty);
      }
```

This way you can pass multiple files ; with different formats and then can be used on single config object to be used in your application.